# Downloading Aster level 1T product?

Tags: image, satellite, aster

When I try to download Aster level 1T data from  the [USGS Earth Explorer site](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) it asks me to enter my username and password over and over when I click on download link of my desired product.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you register on USGS site?

Comment: While you are attempting to obtain GIS data, this isn't really a GIS question, just a plain vanilla IT one. You haven't specified what browser you are using, or whether a problem is reported with the HTTPS session. You should first try a different browser, then hunt about the site for browser requirements, to make sure it will work. After that, this may become a customer service issue. Note that late Friday night/early AM Saturday is a prime maintenance outage window in the US, so the problem might just go away if you wait a few hours.